# Filtering rows based on True or False values of various columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

(English is not my native language, I'll try doing my best to explain my doubt)

I have a Dataframe that has the data of a app and I want to divide it in two other DFs, the first one containing the premium users of this app and the other one having the rest of the data.

The conditions for being a premium member are having at last one True value on the determined columns, in otherwise, the non premium members don't have a True value on any of the following columns:

```
list_of_columns = [column1, column2, column3, column4, ..., columnN]
```

I got the users' df doing:

```
for column in list_of_columns:
    if list_of_columns.index(column) == 0:
        users_df = df.loc[data[column] == True]
    else:
        users_df = pd.concat([users_df, df.loc[data[column] == True]])
users_df = users_df.drop_duplicates()
```

I could get the other one, the non_users_df doing something like this:

```
non_users_df = df.loc[(df[column1] == False) &
                                         (data[column1] == False) &
                                         (data[column2] == False) &
                                         (data[column3] == False) &
                                         (data[...] == False) &
                                         (data['columnN'] == False)]
```

I'm satisfied in the way I built my users_df, but I think that must have another way to get the non_users_df, specially cause there's a lot of columns in the conditional (even my way getting me a correct df).

Could someone help me please?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are two more elegant solutions for both:

```
# Leaving rows if one True exists
users_df = df[~((~df).all(axis=1))]

# Leaving rows that are all False
non_users_df = df[((~df).all(axis=1))]
```

If you are looking to make the criteria on only some of the columns in the dataset:

```
cols = ['column1', 'column2']

# Leaving rows if one True exists
users_df = df[~((~df[cols]).all(axis=1))]

# Leaving rows that are all False
non_users_df = df[((~df[cols]).all(axis=1))]
```

Comment: `df[~((~df).all(axis=1))]` this seems like you can simplify it by using `df.any()` instead of `(~df).all()`